# MonacaのGithub連携ができなくなった

Tags: monaca, github

MonacaからGithubのprivateリポジトリへの連携ができなくなり、一覧にも表示されなくなりました。
Personalプランでは使えなくなってしまったのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

プラン説明上はPersonal以上であれば、Github プライベートリポジトリは連携可能です。
（参考 https://monaca.mobi/ja/pricing）

Comment: ありがとうございます。であれば、やはり自分のアカウントか環境がおかしいのですね・・・。